# backup from ZynOS but, can not be decompressed with LZS

Tags: static-analysis, unpacking

So I have this rom-0 file from Zyxel router P-660HW-T3 v3 and I would like to decompress it, I tried many tools, one of them [you can find here](http://git.kopf-tisch.de/?p=zyxel-revert;a=summary) the tool using lzs for decompression which works for some rom-0 files (smaller ones around 16 kB), but on mine it does not, mine has around 50 kB and has few differences.Here is "normal" file

```
00000000  01 01 00 01 19 48 64 62  67 61 72 65 61 00 00 00  |.....Hdbgarea...|
00000010  00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00  01 48 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........H......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  52 ca c0 ea de ad be af  |........R.......|
00000170  00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  05 03 00 ad 52 c9 a4 e5  80 46 e7 50 ff ff a1 f4  |....R....F.P....|
00000190  00 00 00 19 00 00 00 00  05 03 00 d4 52 c9 a4 e5  |............R...|
000001a0  80 46 e7 50 ff ff 9e 08  00 00 00 64 80 09 89 ac  |.F.P.......d....|
000001b0  04 03 00 d5 52 c9 bb 21  80 46 eb b8 ff ff a2 30  |....R..!.F.....0|
000001c0  00 09 3a c9 00 00 00 00  04 03 00 d6 52 c9 bb 21  |..:.........R..!|
000001d0  80 46 eb b8 ff ff a2 2f  00 09 3a c9 00 00 00 00  |.F...../..:.....|
000001e0  04 03 00 d7 52 c9 ba 49  80 46 eb b8 ff ff a2 35  |....R..I.F.....5|
000001f0  52 c9 ba 49 00 00 00 00  04 03 00 d8 52 c9 ba 49  |R..I........R..I|
```

and

```
00000410  80 46 e7 50 ff ff 9e 08  00 00 00 64 80 09 8b 3c  |.F.P.......d...<|
00000420  55 55 55 55 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |UUUU............|
00000430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000006d0  00 00 00 00 55 55 55 55  00 00 00 00 80 41 00 00  |....UUUU.....A..|
000006e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0e  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  |................|
000006f0  00 00 00 00 ff ff ff fe  00 00 ff 14 00 00 00 01  |................|
00000700  00 00 00 30 00 00 00 01  80 45 cc f0 00 00 00 01  |...0.....E......|
00000710  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 63  80 41 4c 78 00 00 00 01  |.......c.ALx....|
```

and

```
00002000  02 94 00 03 1f fc 62 6f  6f 74 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......boot......|
00002010  00 00 00 00 00 20 00 0c  01 48 73 70 74 2e 64 61  |..... ...Hspt.da|
00002020  74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  1a b0 13 52 01 68 61 75  |t..........R.hau|
00002030  74 6f 65 78 65 63 2e 6e  65 74 00 00 01 f4 01 dc  |toexec.net......|
00002040  1c 18 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

Here is mine

```
00000000  01 01 00 01 00 00 19 48  64 62 67 61 72 65 61 00  |.......Hdbgarea.|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  01 48 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.H..............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 de ad be af  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  03 03 00 30 38 6d 46 1a  00 00 00 18 ff ff a1 f4  |...08mF.........|
00000190  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 03 00 5c 38 6d 46 1a  |...........\8mF.|
000001c0  00 00 00 18 ff ff 9e 08  00 00 00 64 80 09 e0 5c  |...........d...\|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  05 03 00 32 38 6d 46 2a  00 00 00 20 ff ff a1 f4  |...28mF*... ....|
00000200  00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 03 00 5d 38 6d 46 2a  |...........]8mF*|
00000230  00 00 00 20 ff ff a2 29  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |... ...)........|
00000240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

```
00000ea0  04 03 00 2e 38 6d 45 ee  00 00 00 20 ff ff a1 f4  |....8mE.... ....|
00000eb0  00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000ec0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000ed0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 03 00 59 38 6d 45 ee  |...........Y8mE.|
00000ee0  00 00 00 20 ff ff a2 33  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |... ...3........|
00000ef0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000f10  04 03 00 5a 38 6d 45 ee  00 00 00 20 ff ff a2 2e  |...Z8mE.... ....|
00000f20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000f40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 03 00 5b 38 6d 45 f7  |...........[8mE.|
00000f50  00 00 00 15 ff ff a5 fc  ff ff f4 47 80 9a e2 98  |...........G....|
00000f60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000f80  55 55 55 55 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |UUUU............|
00000f90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001b90  00 00 00 00 55 55 55 55  00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff  |....UUUU........|
00001ba0  00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

```
00001fd0  80 7a 00 00 bf c0 5f 90  80 66 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.z...._..f......|
00001fe0  80 5e 05 b4 80 40 11 c8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.^...@..........|
00001ff0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002000  02 c8 00 03 00 00 9f fc  62 6f 6f 74 00 00 00 00  |........boot....|
00002010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 20 00 00 00 0c 00 00  |......... ......|
00002020  01 48 73 70 74 2e 64 61  74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.Hspt.dat.......|
00002030  00 00 9a b0 00 00 3f 6c  00 00 01 68 61 75 74 6f  |......?l...hauto|
00002040  65 78 65 63 2e 6e 65 74  00 00 00 00 01 f4 00 00  |exec.net........|
00002050  01 52 00 00 9c 18 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.R..............|
00002060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

I separated some parts of the files as u may see above, so what Binwalk says on "normal" file

```
$ binwalk rom-0

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "dbgarea", compressed size: 0, uncompressed size: 6144, data offset from start of block: 344
8212          0x2014          ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "spt.dat", compressed size: 4946, uncompressed size: 6832, data offset from start of block: 376
8232          0x2028          ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "autoexec.net", compressed size: 476, uncompressed size: 500, data offset from start of block: 7208
```

and what on mine

```
$ binwalk rom-4.51 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2             0x2             ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "dbgarea", compressed size: 6144, uncompressed size: 0, data offset from start of block: 16
7319          0x1C97          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0xD0, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 31360 bytes
8220          0x201C          ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "spt.dat", compressed size: 39600, uncompressed size: 0, data offset from start of block: 16
8246          0x2036          ZyXEL rom-0 configuration block, name: "autoexec.net", compressed size: 500, uncompressed size: 0, data offset from start of block: 16
```

LZMA header is "incorrect" it cant be decompressed, maybe its modified do not know, so file has dbgarea, spt.dat, autoexec.net standard block but is it comoressed with "modified" lzs can u tell ?

> [Here](http://www.hakim.ws/huawei/rom-0/kender.html) are some notes from RE of "old" rom-0

---

so I see that righnt now there "is no help" so I will post whole file so u can see whole picture

Heh I have limitation to 30000 chars so here is link of file 
http://pastebin.com/2X00B6rJ Can any one help me to "reveal" what they did (changed) to lzs compresion, I asume its lzs

Many tnx in advice, cheers

Comment: It's been a while since the last time I played with ZynOS roms but they commonly used the old LZMA algorithm for ARM devices (depending on which LZMA version you're using to decompress it may fail, try downloading + building + using the official LZMA version, not the one that comes with your Linux distro) or BZ2 for the MIPS ones. Or may be it was the other way around; sorry, I do not remember now :/

Comment: You think its modified or old version of LZMA ? Interesting I will try it for sure, tnx on advice

Comment: Uhm... by the way, I downloaded the firmware for this device but, in my case, it isn't LZMA but BZ :? Is yours P-660HW-T3_340UU7C0?

Comment: I cant find that number behind :D
Model Number:P-660HW-T3 v3
ZyNOS Firmware Version:V3.70(BYO.0)
If u like to see it, I can send it to you

Comment: Sure: http://www.joxeankoret.com/contact.html

Comment: LZMA header is fals positive for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's compressed with LZS ( Lempel-Ziv-Stack ).

I was trying to do the password extraction the pythonic way, it's enought to take a look at this shell script and small piece of c code:

[shell + C solution](https://github.com/MrNasro/scripts/blob/master/exploits/rom0x/)

[way of extraction LZS with python](https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/4663892)

and to replace 'dd' usage in same python script:

def romcutter(fname):
    import sys
    fpos=8568
    fend=8788
    fhandle=file(fname)
    fhandle.seek(fpos)
    chunk="*"
    amount=221
    while fpos < fend:
        if fend-fpos < amount:
            amount = fend-fpos
            chunk = fhandle.read(amount)
            fpos += len(chunk)
            return chunk

### take rom-0, cut it with cutter, and extract result LZS....

Answer (score 1):

it's compressed with LZS ( Lempel-Ziv-Stack ).

I was trying to do the password extraction the pythonic way, it's enought to take a look at this shell script and small piece of c code:

[shell + C solution](https://github.com/MrNasro/scripts/blob/master/exploits/rom0x/)

[way of extraction LZS with python](https://gist.github.com/FiloSottile/4663892)

and to replace 'dd' usage in same python script:

```
    def romcutter(fname):
        import sys
        fpos=8568
        fend=8788
        fhandle=file(fname)
        fhandle.seek(fpos)
        chunk="*"
        amount=221
        while fpos < fend:
            if fend-fpos < amount:
                amount = fend-fpos
                chunk = fhandle.read(amount)
                fpos += len(chunk)
                return chunk
```

### take rom-0, cut it with cutter, and extract result LZS....